# Ubuntu updates (nothing occurs)

Tags: updates

When i run Update manager and try to install something, when it starts, says: "Preparing packages" and nothing occurs.

Any idea?

This situation occurs with any package that I choose.

ubuntu version: 10.04

for example

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-37 linux-headers-2.6.32-37-generic linux-image-2.6.32-37-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libarchive1 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
5 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
521 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/43.5MB of archives.
After this operation, 185MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y`
```

Then It hangs...

Try sudo apt-get install -f

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnb-platform10-java kdebase-runtime-data-common libnb-java2-java libwxgtk2.6-0 libswt-gtk-3.5-jni libknotificationitem1 liblogkit-java
  kde-icons-oxygen libexiv2-5 libkadm5clnt6 liblzma0 libmysqlclient15off libnb-ide11-java kdebase-runtime-bin-kde4 libwxbase2.6-0
  tzdata-java python-wxversion libqt4-phonon khelpcenter4 libqt3-mt python-wxgtk2.6 libswt-gtk-3.5-java stardict-plugin-gucharmap
  libreadline5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
520 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
```

It hangs :(

Comment: This could be a silly question, but are you hitting Enter after you type 'y'?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens ? It hangs ? Also it appears you have a number of transactions pending. What happens when you urn `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: of course @Shawn

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yes it hangs.

Comment: It looks moderately broken with insufficient information to know what will fix it. Somewhere in those 500 or so packages, one is broken. Do you recall any previous or error message ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen nothing. is there any log that i can see?

Comment: Look at the files in `/var/log/apt/`. And have patience - not everything is complete in seconds.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this sequence of commands

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```