# Update Manager Error ( Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: updates

System Update marks as an error.

While trying to install updates, errors like this occurs:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5) but it is not installed
libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-20ubuntu5.3) but 2.13-20ubuntu5 is installed
       Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5.3) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
```

Any ideas?

P.S - this is my first experience with Ubuntu, so be patient :)

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/89000/ubuntu-updates-nothing-occurs?rq=1 it is along the same lines as yours and the answer should work for you

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 has reached EOL (End Of Life). You must upgrade to a newer and supported version. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) listed all the versions of Ubuntu. **Stable** are the versions currently supported. Be aware that 10.04 LTS is server only edition (no desktop environment).

Comment: Thanks for other link. I did as it`s told. Indeed, it was similar error but even after commands:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f

It isn`t working. Crash occurs at the very end.

It looks I will try NikTh`s comment and just have new system version.

Comment: @NikTh - no luck in upgrading next version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute these commands. They will help to clear/fix broken packages/dependencies and also try to install required library packages needed:

```
1. Fix using Command Line:
    $ sudo apt-get autoremove
    $ sudo apt-get --purge remove
    $ sudo apt-get autoclean
    $ sudo apt-get clean
    $ sudo apt-get -f install
And then try to upgrade again:
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade

2. Fix using Synaptic Package Manager
```

- Fist install synaptic package manager if you don't have already installed:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install synaptic
  ```
- Then open synaptic package manager -> click **Custom Filters** down-left -> click **Broken** top-left, it will list all broken packages try to all broken packages. Also if any residual packages are there on more option you will get as **residual packages**.
- Search for packages **libc-bin**, **libc-dev-bin**, **libc6** and others **one by one** which have unmet dependencies, select it, chose **Package** from the menu -> **Force Version** and chose some other version from the list. Then click **Apply** to install it.
- Try to upgrade again, if everything goes ok.

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Dear @Saurav Kumar, I did your adive given but everything stopped on trying to install Synaptic Package manager. After command, it recommends me to do this:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5)
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-20ubuntu5.3) but 2.13-20ubuntu5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Are you able to install updates now? Are your system working fine?

Comment: it`s not. I could install Synaptic Manager and also next to the update status it shows:

Error: Broken Count >0

Comment: Ok, one more thing you can try. Restart your system in Safe Mode. This option comes in Boot Menu (2nd Option). When it starts after a lot of texts in black screen, It will display some more options. There you will get one option like "Fix Broken Packages". Go for that allow yes for all questions.

Comment: I`m just confused of all commands and problem solving management.
Before using Safe Mode, I did "apt-get -f install" and not there are some more issues:

Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: I don't know what to say.. :( Your problem is going to be more complex. These type of problems can be solved very easily using Synaptic Package Manager. I used it to solve a lot of problems. I don't know for you why is it becoming so tough. Last thing I prefer you to download Ubuntu 12.04.3 and try to upgrade from the CD, or install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. This is what I could do.. :(